# Cocos2d-x: Differences between applying shader to child node and entire scene?

Tags: shaders, fragment-shader, cocos2d-x

I'm beginning with shader.
I wonder what if i apply shader for single node, what'll happen?

The `gl_FragCoord = (0.5,0.5)` is the bottom left of the screen or the bottom left of the node?

I get some wrong caculations while wanting to draw something in the center of the node (not the screen).

Many shader tutorias with sample code to draw at center using `gl_FragCoord.xy / resolution.xy`, if it's 0.5, it's center. In this case, it might be wrong because i want to draw in center of the node.

Finally, how's about `texture2D` i use `texture2D` instead of `texture`, are they the same?

I've applied this code on the node and it prints out the whole screen with stretch version (resolution = device resolution)

```
vec2 xy = gl_FragCoord.xy / resolution.xy;
vec4 texColor = texture2D(CC_Texture0,xy);
gl_FragColor = texColor;
```

Comment: Shader code doesn't know about nodes or scenes - it is run on the GPU. Therefore you need to calculate the proper position of your pixels (which every proper tutorial should show)

Comment: @UnholySheep Thanks, because i don't know why if i test the shader code on ShaderToy, it works. But i apply it to the node, it's wrong. So i though using `gl_FragCoord.xy / resolution.xy` is wrong in this case to get position of pixel on the node?

Comment: `gl_FragCoord.xy / resolution.xy` is the center of the viewport (assuming that `resolution` is the viewport resolution like it is in ShaderToy). To get the center of the node you need to either pass the node's coordinates into the shader and calculate the screen pixels from that or do the calculation CPU side and pass the coordinates into the shader

Comment: Thank. So it means applying shader to screen or node makes no difference here? Every opengl function applies for the whole screen? I have to ask because if the node (drawNode) is small, i can't see what has been rendering outside of it until it become larger, so i though shader apply to the node layer only. If i remove this node, i can't see the shader result?

Comment: Shaders are run on the GPU which doesn't know anything about nodes. However if a node is considered to be invisible (e.g.: outside the camera's view) by the engine it will never run it's shader code

Comment: @UnholySheep After certain time of testing. I still don't understand if GPU doesn't know about nodes, why applying same shader for node bring up different result with shadertoy? `gl_FragCoord.xy / resolution.xy` is the position of pixel from 0 to 1, if resolution = screen resolution, except applying to node has different input like: pixel location / resolution ... ?