# Difference between "texture" vs "texture2d" in OpenGL ES?

Tags: opengl, textures, opengl-es

I see many example in shadertoy use `texture`, but in the cocos2d-x, only `texture2d`.

Does `texture` use normalized coordinate and `texture2d` doesn't?
Because when I use `texture2d`, it returns wrong result.

Answer (score 7):

`texture2D` is the same as `texture`, but it's used in the older versions of glsl.

Between glsl 120 and 130 they changed the function to `texture` and made it accept every kind of samplers, not just a `sampler2D`.

There's no difference between them, so the problem is probably in your code.

Comment: It's weird, because the shader works well on shadertoy (shadertoy only works with `texture`), but when i apply it to the node, it renders wrong. And i realize that if i change the parameter for `texture2d` as pixel coordinate - normalized coordinate, it works. You can see the question here: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/138333/cocos2d-x-differences-between-applying-shader-to-child-node-and-entire-scene

Comment: @Tom As others pointed out below that question, there's no difference between normal shader code and shader code you use for cocos-2d. It doesn't know about nodes, and if something's wrong, it's a mistake from your side